# Too many arguments using a String in MailSystem.Net

Tags: c#, imap

I'm trying to connect to an IMAP server using MailSystem.Net. everything seems ok until I attempt to use this code with a password that contains more then one word(a requirement for using this code to access any of the actual nontest emails I am going to be using it on). At that point I receive a "too many arguments" error to the login command.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using CommandLine.Utility;
using ActiveUp.Net.Mail;
using PT.MailIntegration.IMAP; // not using this, could be removed



namespace MailP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string user = null;
            string password = null;
            string server = null;
            string path = null;

            // this sends the args string into the CommdandLine class and dumps any values into a hashtable
            Arguments CommandLine = new Arguments(args);

            // sets the user
            if (CommandLine["u"] != null)
            {
                user = CommandLine["u"];
            }

            // sets the password
            if (CommandLine["p"] != null)
            {
                password = CommandLine["p"];
            }

            // sets the server
            if (CommandLine["s"] != null)
            {
                server = CommandLine["s"];
            }

            // sets the path
            if (CommandLine["d"] != null)
            {
                @path = CommandLine["d"];
            }

            // program only moves forward as long as it has these 4 arguments
            if ((user != null) &
                (password != null) &
                (server != null) &
                (path != null))
            {
                Imap4Client client = new Imap4Client();
                Console.WriteLine(" " + user + " " + password + " " + server + " " + path);
                client.ConnectSsl(server, 993);
                client.Login(user, password);  //this is where the error pops up
                // this print out means we got in!
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Successful!");

                Mailbox box = client.Mailboxes["inbox"];
                Fetch fetch = box.Fetch;
                int messagesLeft = box.MessageCount;
                int msgIndex = 0;

                while (messagesLeft > 0)
                {
                    msgIndex++;
                    messagesLeft--;
                    Message email = fetch.MessageObject(msgIndex);

                    // if the email has attachments
                    if (email.Attachments.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (MimePart attachment in email.Attachments)
                        {
                            email.Attachments.StoreToFolder(@path);
                            Console.WriteLine("Downloaded!");
                        }
                    }

                    // delete the message using it's UID and position in the mailbox
                    box.UidDeleteMessage(fetch.Uid(msgIndex), true);
                    msgIndex--;
                }

            }
            // this means the user did not enter the expected arguments
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You did not enter the expected data!\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Format should be: ");
                Console.WriteLine("MailP.exe -u <user> -p <password> -s <IMAP SERVER> -d <path>");

                Console.WriteLine("\r\n" + "Press any key to continue...");
                Console.ReadKey(true);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

for the input:

> mailP.exe -u "username" -password "this is my password" -s
>   "imap.server.com" -d "c:\downloads"

I get the error:

> {"Command \"login username this is my password \" failed :
>   130312093815354 BAD Unexpected extra arguments to LOGIN\r\n"}

I've tried casting the password string as string in the call to login. I've also tried having the login be part of another function that takes in two strings as arguments. I'm guessing that something isn't parsing the quotes properly in the login function perhaps? If it's that I haven't been able to find another person on the web with a similar issue. Even hard coding the password gives the same issue. I'm totally at a loss here. I want the entire string to be passed in as the argument to password. I know it's got to be something silly that I've missed but I've been over this code backwards and am missing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the password contains spaces, I am betting that you simply have to surround it by quotes.

```
client.Login(user, "\"" + password + "\"");
```

Comment: You, sir, are the wind beneath my wings. This absolutely solved the problem. Thank you!