# How to get UID from ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Message or how to search by MessageId?

Tags: c#, imap

I want to search and delete messages with `ActiveUp.Net.Mail` library on IMAP4 service. I don't know how to get UID from `ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Message` or how to search mailbox with selected folder if I know MessageId.

Of course I have previously fetched messages so I know its `MessageId`.

Best Regards.

Comment: If you are using `ActiveUp.Net.Mail`, do they not have a `FAQ` site..? what have you tried or done in regards to researching this issue on your own on the `Internet`..?

Comment: I found answer there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363586/too-many-arguments-using-a-string-in-mailsystem-net and also is DeleteMethod which takes order number.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late but I faced the same problem today so, maybe there are other people still looking for the answer. Here is the solution that worked for me:

```cs
// Select the Mailbox you want to query
Mailbox Inbox = _client.SelectMailbox("Inbox");

for (int x=Inbox.MessageCount; x>0; x--)
{
    Message email = Inbox.Fetch.MessageObject(x);
    ProcessEmail(email, x);
}
```

Basically the messageOrdinal is the index of the mail (for example: the position in the gmail Inbox), but you have to keep the reference by yourself because ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Message won't provide any function to retrieve it.

In the `ProcessEmail` function you will receive the `messageOrdinal` as input parameter:

```cs
public void ProcessEmail(Message email, int messageOrdinal)
{
    //...
}
```